# Kotlin firebase read object from db

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem reading an object from the db without reading the single fields ad recostructing the object manually.
A simple example of the code.

This is my model:

```
    data class Ingredient(val name: String, val quantity: Int){

    }

                                        // yes, just one ingredient for the moment =)
    data class Recipe(val name: String, val ingredient: Ingredient){

    }
```

Then I save an instance on db:

```
    val i1 = Ingredient("ing1", 300)
    val r = Recipe("rec1", i1)
    val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    db.collection("recipies").document(r.name).set(r.ingredient)
```

Finally I try to read the ingredient:

```
    db.collection("recipies").document(r.name).addSnapshotListener {
            documentSnapshot, _ ->
        if(documentSnapshot != null){
            val ingredient: Ingredient? = documentSnapshot.get("ingredient", Ingredient::class.java)
        }
    }
```

The problem is that ingredient is null.
How can I fix the problem?

I had a model with a list, but I found out that even this simpler example did not work.

This is the db structure:
[image: db]

Comment: Please post database strucuture

Comment: I updated the post with a link to the structure. thanks

Comment: You say "The problem is that ingredient is null.", how do you check that? Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo I found the issue. The data class must have default values.

Answer (score 2):

```
db.collection("recipies").document(r.name).addSnapshotListener {
        val ingredient = documentSnapshot?.toObject(Ingredient::class.java) //<-- Use .toObject instead
    }
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.